# How do I seperate text by lines in this divider?

Tags: javascript, html, function, divider

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<center>
    <div id="output" style="width:1000px; height:800px; background-color:grey; word-wrap: break-word;"></div> //divider is here
</center>
</body>
<script>
var printOut = function(text) {
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  output.innerHTML += text;
};
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose Rock, Paper, or Scissors?") 
    console.log(printOut("You chose " + userChoice + ".")); //Used here..
var computerChoice = Math.random();
  if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "Rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "Paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "Scissors";
} console.log(printOut("The computer chooses " + computerChoice + ".")); //Here too..

var compareChoice = function(userChoice, computerChoice) {
    if(userChoice === computerChoice) {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }    
    if (userChoice === "Rock") {
       if(computerChoice === "Scissors") {
            return "You win! Rock smashes Scissors!";
        } else {
            return "You lose! Paper covers Rock!";
        }
    }    
    if (userChoice === "Paper") {
        if(computerChoice === "Rock") {
            return "You win! Paper covers Rock!";
        } else {
            return "You lose! Scissors cut Paper!!"
        }
    }    
    if (userChoice === "Scissors") {
        if (computerChoice === "Paper") {
            return "You win! Scissors cut Paper!";
        } else {
            return "You lose! Rock smashes Scissors!";
        }
    }
};

console.log(printOut(compareChoice(userChoice, computerChoice))); //Lastly, here.


</script>
</html>
```

How do I get the results to be on separate lines like:

"You chose Rock.

The computer chose Scissors.

Rock smashes Scissors. You win!"

as opposed to

"You chose Rock. The computer chose Scissors. Rock smashes Scissors. You win!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML `<br />` tag is used to separate lines. However, you can also use `<pre></pre>` to render text as code. Then, you can separate using magic endline character: `\n'.

If you want to use the `\n` your HTML must look like this:

```
<center>
    <pre id="output" style="width:1000px; height:800px; background-color:grey; word-wrap: break-word;"></pre> //divider is here
</center>
```

In that case, put `\n` wherever you want a new line. Also, every space ( ) will be rendered - just like in gray code block here on StackOverflow.

Alternativelly, you can also use CSS style `whitespace:pre` on any element.

#### [JSFiddle example you to properly append and create a log](http://jsfiddle.net/Darker/6bcLduxd/)

**Note:**
I want to warn you, that appending text into HTML as **string** will cause the browser to re-parse the HTML in that node. When your log is longer, this can cause lags.

This is the correct way to append plain text:

```
function addText(text, idOrNode) {
    if(idOrNode.tagName==null)
      idOrNode = document.getElementById(idOrNode);
    if(idOrNode==null)
      throw new Error("Can't append text - the element is invalid.");
    var text_element = document.createTextNode(text);
    idOrNode.appendChild(text_element);
}
```

Comment: Ok. I am completely new to programming of any type, so excuse my dumb questions, but, how would I implement this?

Comment: I have created a complex [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Darker/6bcLduxd/) for you. Feel free to ask any question you have about it.

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one way to force them to show up on new lines, but the simplest is to add the line break tag `<br>` into the strings wherever you want to start a new line.  For example:

```
console.log(printOut("You chose " + userChoice + ".<br>"));
```

Alternately, you can wrap each line of text in a block html element like `<div>` or `<p>` like so:

```
console.log(printOut("<p>You chose " + userChoice + ".</p>"));
```

Comment: This worked, I was using the tag outside of the quotations. Thanks for the example!